# How to Record video with GPUImage?

Tags: android, gpuimage, android-gpuimageview

i used https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage but its just save images.
how to record video using GLSurfaceview?

Answer (score 2):

android-gpuimage library does not support video recording but you can try using the android-gpuimage-videorecording library. It is a fork of the gpu-image for android that provides also the video recording functionality

[android-gpuimage-videorecording](https://github.com/westbrett/android-gpuimage-videorecording)

see the GPUImageMovieWriter class

It should point you in the right direction for developing your own video writer on top of GPUImage.

The idea is to:

- draw on current screen surface
- switch to encoder input surface and draw previous frame buffer again on it
- switch back to screen surface

other useful links: [EGL surface helper](https://github.com/google/grafika), [Media encoder](https://github.com/saki4510t/AudioVideoRecordingSample)

Comment: can you guide how to import setting od gpu image in android studio?

Comment: I am not sure about what are you looking for ... if you do not need the video recording I suggest you to use the original library https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage
If you need video recording you have to export the code from the forked library adding it to your android studio project.